# An application of a criterion for nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras, nilpotence

*I was studying the following criterion:*

---

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $E$ a $k$-vector space of finite dimension, $B\subset A$ two sub-vector spaces of $\mathscr L(E)$.

Let's define $T:=\{t\in \mathscr L(E),\ \mathrm{ad}_t(A)\subset B\}$, where $\mathrm{ad}_t\in \mathscr L(\mathscr L(E))$ is defined as $\mathrm{ad}_t(s)=ts-st$.

> If $t\in T$ is such that for all $u\in T$, $\mathrm{Tr}(tu)=0$, then $t$ is **nilpotent**.

---

**The question:** do you know any application where this criterion is used?

Comment: A lot of Lie theory pops up in quantum field theory, so that'd be my first guess.

Comment: I've never seen an application of this criterion other than as a step in proving Cartan's criterion for solvability in terms of the Killing form.

Comment: @levap So an application would be Cartan's criterion for solvabilité I guess. Thank you very much!

Comment: @E.Joseph: I meant that one shouldn't probably bother too much in trying to remember the statement of the criterion because its (only?) application is to prove the Cartan criterions so one should focus on remembering the Cartan criterions and those criterions have tons of applications :)

Comment: @levap I understand. Though I found this criterion, and I wondered what it was used for, now I can say: *Cartan's criterions*, so it is fine for me.